# Move Azure Virtual network to another resource group

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-resource-group

Hello Im trying to move a Virtual Network from one resource group to another but I received the following error:

> {"code":"ResourceMoveProviderValidationFailed","message":"Resource
>   move validation failed. Please see details. Diagnostic information:
>   ,"details":[{"target":"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks","message":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"CannotMoveResource\",\"message\":\"Cannot
>   move one or more resources in the request. Please check details for
>   information about each
>   resource.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"CannotMoveVnetDueToPeering\",\"message\":\"Cannot
>   move virtual network
>   /subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/RG_Networking/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/XXX
>   because it's peered with other virtual networks:
>   /subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/RG_Networking/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/XXX.\"}]}}"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you need to remove the peering before moving the vnet, you cannot move a vnet that has peering enabled. this is a platform limitation